# Dynamic table with fixed numbers of columns and horizontal RepeatDirection in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html

I would like to make a table with a fixed numbers of columns. The DataSource contains a list of strings that i would like to show in a simple table without borders, headers or anything else than just plain text. I have tried with a DataList with property `RepeatDirection="Horizontal"`, but i don't know how to define columns and how to bind the values from the datasource in each column like this:

```
Column 1          Column 2          Column 3
A                 B                 C
D                 E                 F
```

If anyone does not have an idea I will just make a plain table and add columns, rows and content from codebehind.

Comment: Can you not use ListView here?

Answer (score 0):

The `DataGrid` or `ListView` controls are your best choice. Personally, I prefer the second one. [Here](http://basgun.wordpress.com/2007/12/27/listview-control-in-aspnet-35-1/) you have an example about its use.

With those controls you just have to define a template for each row and bind your data to it. You can also define another template for alternate items, manage sorting by columns, paging, etc.

Comment: Can anyone bring me a contrete example how to do it the easiest way? As i see it, I still have some issues using a ListView, because I have to insert the items manually from codebehind, and check if they belong to column 1, 2 or 3. Or have I missed some functionality of ListView?

Comment: Nope. No need to add each item manually. Have you seen the link I've posted?

Comment: Yep. I have seen the link. But as far as I can see it is not solving the issue about adding the first item to column 1, the second item to column 2, the third item to column 3 and then adding the fourth item to column 1 and so on... Have I missed something?

Comment: Your datasource is just a list of strings? Like `List(Of String)`? No objects, no nothing?

Comment: Actually it is a list of objects which contains two properties, ID (int) and Sentence (String), but I want to show strings only - in the way I explained before

Comment: I see... Sorry, I didn't understand you. Then maybe the codebehind hard coding is not such a bad option.